Is it safe to use dataclasses with hidden/non-field inherited properties?
I have a dataclass use strategy that is quite flexible, but I am unsure if it is relying on features that aren't part of the type contract. I am often telling people to not rely on the insertion order being the iterable order of a dict in python because only the OrderedDict has that property as a contract and a different version of python may behave differently.
Are there any concerns with patterning like this? It gives me a lot of flexibility to leverage the features of a dataclass that have a separation of properties like this.
from abc import ABC
from dataclasses import dataclass, fields

class BQTransformer(ABC):
    _project: str = 'default-project-name'
    _dataset_wo_version: str
    _dataset_version: str
    _default_table: str

    @classmethod
    def get_dataset(cls):
        return f'{cls._dataset_wo_version}_v{cls._dataset_version}'

    @classmethod
    def table(cls, table_name=None) -> str:
        if table_name is None:
            table_name = cls._default_table
        return f'{cls._project}.{cls.get_dataset()}.{table_name}'


@dataclass(frozen=True, eq=True)
class BilliardsUser(BQTransformer):
    _dataset_wo_version = 'billiards_info'
    _dataset_version = '20240830'
    _default_table = 'users'
    username: str
    id: int


A = BilliardsUser(username='Philip', id=3)
B = BilliardsUser(username='James', id=7)

>>> [f.name for f in fields(A)]
['username', 'id']
>>> A.table()
'default-project-name.billiards_info_v20240830.users'


FYI, dictionaries retaining insertion order has been part of the language specification since 3.7. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980323/are-dictionaries-ordered-in-python-3-6

Since Python 3.6 dictionaries do maintain insertion order, and since Python 3.7 that has become part of the language specification.
So,if that is the problem you are facing, just use it as is.  It is really hard to tell what is the part you are in doubt about, by looking at your example code.
One side note is that if you are not making use of @abstractmethod, there is no reason to make use of the ABC base - it has no effect in the final code, but the semantic advice that it BQTransformer should not be instantiated directly (but it won't prevent that).
